# When I tried to get input from the Form on ruby on rails, I am getting back hash array instant of simple name. How to solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Here is my HTML code

```
<h1>Create new Cat</h1>
<form action="/cats" method= "POST">
    <input type="text" name="cat[name]">

    <input type="submit" value="Create Cat!">
</form>
```

When I try to get the input with the above code by typing **Loki** in the box as cat name, I got **Parameters: {"cat"=>{"name"=>"Loki"}}**, the saved name become **{"name"=>"Loki"}** and the Json format is **{"id":19,"name":"{"name"=\u003e"Loki"}","created_at":"2021-11-07T07:03:50.140Z","updated_at":"2021-11-07T07:03:50.140Z"}**.

**What I am expecting to get is just "Loki".**

This is my create method from cats_controller.rb

```
    def create
        #POST /cats
        @cat = Cat.new(name: params[:cat].permit(:name))
        if @cat.save
            redirect_to cat_url(@cat)
        else
            render :new
            #render json: @cat.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are much better of using strong parameters as is the Rails standard of doing things. `params[:cat].permit(:name)` just permits the params, doesn't read from it, you would have to do `params[:cat].permit(:name)[:name]` to get to the name itself.

As said however, this is the Rails way of doing this, much cleaner code.

```rb
def create
  @cat = Cat.new(safe_params)
  # ...
end

def safe_params
  params[:cat].permit(:name)
end
```